# JPanel, не удается рисовать фигуры

Tags: java, swing

Среда разрбаботки Netbeans.

Если создать вручную класс унаследованный от JPanel и реализовать в нем необходимые методы, а затем добавить этот Jpanel в JFrame, то в дальнейшем на этом Jpanel все успешно рисуется.

Но в таком случае очень сложно настраивать позиционирование элементов на JFrame.
Поэтому я решил создать с помощью средств IDE JFrame, затем с использованием палитры располагать на нем элементы, в том числе JPanel.

Но в таком случае как рисовать на Jpanel? Ведь отдельного класса для него нет.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку не представлено кода, могу догадаться что добавление на JFrame было такое:

```
myFrame.add(myJPanel);
```

Установки layout явно не производилось и поэтому стоит flowLayout, который заполняет всё пространство. Для того что бы располагать ещё какие либо элементы на JFrame, необходимо задать настройки layout. Допустим GridLayout или GridBagLayout.
К примеру так.

```
MyFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)